# SQL Date Conversion in Apache Commons BeanUtils

Tags: java, type-conversion, apache-commons-beanutils

I have two Java beans `A` and `B` with the same properties and types with the exception that all dates in `A` are `java.sql.Date` and all dates in `B` are `java.time.LocalDate`. I want to use Apache Commons `BeanUtils` to copy values of all properties from bean `A` to bean `B`. How do I do this with proper date conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I was on the search myself. The only thing I found so far, is to write a Converter on your own.

As you can see on the current repository of [commons-beanutils](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-beanutils.git;a=tree;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/beanutils2/converters;h=afd97c344dd733b61da056d119124d3255e712b2;hb=5da3cdee9dbc9684c258074d5e75991e2abf4787) a general Converter which supports `java.time` is in the making.

For writing your own, you could use the current state of theirs as a reference. I'd advice you to make decent UnitTests, as the current state of that converter isn't officially released yet.